# Does pymongo.insert_one guerantee availiability of the document?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

If I do some DB insertion and fetch a document instantly after it returns an *id*, like this:

```
id = mongo.database.collection.insert_one(document)
document = mongo.database.collection.find_one({"_id": id})
```

Is it guaranteed that Mongo will already process the document when returning the *id*, so I can get it with *find_one* right after?

Comment: If you use acknowledged inserts, then yes.

Comment: https://emptysqua.re/blog/pymongos-new-default-safe-writes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @favoretti mentioned, new (>= 2.4) versions of PyMongo [do](https://emptysqua.re/blog/pymongos-new-default-safe-writes/) acknowledged writes by default when using MongoClient, so document availability is guaranteed.